# Books not detecting current reading

Tags: bug, books

Apple's Books app on iOS has stopped detecting books I'm currently reading in "Reading Now". In order to get a recent book to appear in the list, I need have it open in the app, force quite the app, and reboot my iOS device.

How do I get Books to correctly show recently current activity in "Reading Now" on iOS?